# Python class in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to add a new Python class within an existing Collab project which is already working with a similar structure using classes within files within a sub file director (filedir). I have placed the new class, NewClassMethod, within a new_class.py file and put it into a directory. However, I am getting an error:

```
cannot import name 'NewClassMethod' from 'filedir1.filedir2'
```

There is a `__init__.py` file within that subdirectory of filedir2, but I haven't added anything to that. I am not sure if the error is related.

Thanks for any help. The full error is:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-f73c71e55f75> in <module>
----> 1 from filedir1.filedir2 import NewClassMethod
      2 nn = NewClassMethod()  

ImportError: cannot import name 'NewClassMethod' from 'cs231n.classifiers' (/content/drive/MyDrive/filedir1/filedir2/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please show the full error trace.

Comment: if you have an `__init__.py` file, your class, declared as  a block starting with `class NewClassMethod: `  should be in that file, or imported from a sibling file into it (the `__init__.oy`file)

Comment: this however, can have too slow a feedback cycle for you to understand how to work with packages, modules and classes in a timely manner. 
You; d better play around with these concepts in a local install, with the native REPL, or idle - were changes and errors will be instantaneous, and later move back to an online notebook such as colaboratory

Comment: Thanks jsbueno. Your second comment was particularly helpful. I was able to do a local run-through to better understand how this all works and it is working now in Colab I believe.